# Tomcat 10 - jakarta.faces - Tomcat does not start

Tags: java-11, tomcat10

I am in the process of converting a Java 11 project with JSP and JSF web sites from javax.* to jakarta.*. For this I ...

- updated Tomcat 9 to 10
- updated all dependencies to the latest versions (build.gradle dependencies see below)
- changed all imports (javax -> jakarta)
- updated config files (web.xml, beans.xml, context.xml, faces-config.xml see below)

But unfortunately Tomcat 10 won't start now (StackTrace see below). I only get it to start when I remove jakarta.faces from the dependencies, but then no JSF pages run anymore, only JSP. So this is not a solution.

Does anyone maybe have a good idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

**Exceptions:**

```
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.320 INFORMATION [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Mojarra 3.0.1 fÃ¼r Kontext '' wird initialisiert.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.536 INFORMATION [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.806 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2517)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:410)
        at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:338)
        at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:183)
        at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:264)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:289)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:283)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:198)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:263)
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:261)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1873)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1444)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
        ... 69 more
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.806 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.806 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
14:25:00 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  (org.jboss.weld.environment.servletWeldServlet) [EnhancedListener.java:75] - WELD-ENV-001009: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener used for ServletRequest and HttpSession notifications
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.906 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:559)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addEL3_0_Resolvers(ELUtils.java:317)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:243)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:463)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:183)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:122)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:206)
        at jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:631)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:335)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5426)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1873)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2f43a77d]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@2f34dd35]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2070279c]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@6a9c3d09]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@706f2549]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.MutableInstant] (value [MutableInstant[epochSecond=1624361213, nano=607000000]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@7b902a38]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@13951f65]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@57728a91]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.MutableInstant] (value [MutableInstant[epochSecond=1624361213, nano=861000000]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5e3ea85b]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@2485884e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1fd0d58c]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@5c35f2e5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@77e2e548]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.FixedFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$FixedFormatter@7f2dd402]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.922 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@66c812de]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.MutableInstant] (value [MutableInstant[epochSecond=1624361213, nano=407000000]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.937 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@15197638]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@75b10976]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
22-Jun-2021 14:25:00.937 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@642d5e06]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.MutableInstant] (value [MutableInstant[epochSecond=1624361213, nano=739000000]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

**build.gradle dependencies:**

```java
runtimeOnly ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3') {
    because 'log4j yaml layout'
}
runtimeOnly ('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.12.3') {
    because 'log4j yaml layout'
}

implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.14.1') {
    because 'ireasoning snmp agent'
}
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.14.1'
implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
implementation 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-shaded:4.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:3.0.1'
implementation 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:2.0.0'
implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.primefaces:primefaces:10.0.0'
implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.1'
implementation ('commons-io:commons-io:2.10.0') {
    because 'commons-fileupload loads outdated version 2.2'
}
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.8'

providedCompile 'jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:9.1.0'
providedCompile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.8.0'
providedCompile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
providedCompile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.10.0'
providedCompile 'com.ireasoning:snmpagent:6.5.24c'
providedCompile 'com.neuronrobotics:nrjavaserial:3.15.0c'

compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:10.0.7'
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true"
>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.weld.development</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>        
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>jakarta.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

**beans.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

**context.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
    <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
</Context>
```

**faces-config.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
>
    <!-- Your faces config here. -->
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`primefaces`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces/10.0.0) 10.0.0 comes in two versions: a Java EE compatible one (default) and a Jakarta EE 9 version.

You need to add the `jakarta` classifier to select the second version:

```
implementation 'org.primefaces:primefaces:10.0.0:jakarta'
```

**Remark**: Since you depend on Spring, you must wait with your migration until Spring 6.x (Jakarta EE 9 compatible) is out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the solution to the problem. 